# Why is this switch case not working in Netbeans?

Tags: java, switch-statement

Switch case is taking value but only the default case is running.

```
int z = Integer.parseInt(x);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,+z);
    switch (z) {
    case ('1'):
        C.SetEmpInformation();
        break;
    case ('2'):
        C.UpdateEmpInformation();
        break;
    default:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Identity");
}
```

Comment: '1' is a character, not the number 1. Is the value in the variable `z` `1` or `49` (the ASCII value of character 1)? Also as a stylistic thing, the parentheses in the case labels look weird and may confuse people.

Comment: try `case 1:` and `case 2:`

Comment: Note that your example would not have worked on Eclipse either.  If it did, the chances are that the code was different.  (This is basic Java ... not an IDE difference.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the single quotes in your case statements. They will be matched as `char` and not as `int`. '1' is a `character` and very different from the number 1.

```
 switch (z) {
   case 1: /* .... */
   case 2: /* .... */
   default : /* .... */
}
```

You wouldn't need the brackets as well.

Answer (score 1):

The type you are checking in your `case` statements is wrong, you compare an `int` (`z`) to a `char` (`'1'`).

You need to write your `case`s like this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, + z); // btw, what is this + doing here?
    switch (z) {
    case 1:
        C.SetEmpInformation();
        break;
    case 2:
        C.UpdateEmpInformation();
        break;
    default:
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid Identity");
        break;
}
```

Comment: thank you so much, it worked but this program is running happily in Eclipse.Why?

Comment: You haven't writte wrong code from the compiler's perspective, it seems valid to it. The problem was that it wasn't working the way you wanted it to...

Answer (score 0):

It works for me in NetBeans too, so if it does not even start on your machine, you may have some verification tool, linter, something like that.
Anyway, what you write is correct Java code, just probably it will not do what you expect, and that is what the message may indicate.
You can `switch` on numbers, characters and Strings, all of them work. Just do not mix them: they either will not compile (mixing numbers/characters with String), or will work in a probably unexpected way (mixing numbers with characters), because `1` is a number but `'1'` is a character, which is represented by its ASCII code as a number, 49.

Test code:

```
String x="1";
int z=Integer.parseInt(x);
switch(z){
  case ('1'): System.out.println(z+" is '1'");break;
  default: System.out.println(z+" is not '1'");
}

x="49";
z=Integer.parseInt(x);
switch(z){
  case ('1'): System.out.println(z+" is '1'");break;
  default: System.out.println(z+" is not '1'");
}

x="1";
z=Integer.parseInt(x);
switch(z){
  case 1: System.out.println(z+" is 1");break;
  default: System.out.println(z+" is not 1");
}

switch(x.charAt(0)){
  case '1': System.out.println("\"1\".charAt(0) is '1'");break;
  default: System.out.println("\"1\".charAt(0) is not '1'");
}

switch(x){
  case "1": System.out.println("\""+x+"\" is \"1\"");break;
  default: System.out.println("\""+x+"\" is not \"1\"");
}
```

Output:

> ```
> 1 is not '1'
> 49 is '1'
> 1 is 1
> "1".charAt(0) is '1'
> "1" is "1"
> ```